# How to get the current month and based on the month get the last two months in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How to get the current month and based on the month get the last two months in Angular 2?

I get the current month like this:

```
private _createMonthList(): any {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setMonth(d.getMonth());
            console.log('MONTH', d);
    }
```

But what i wanted is a list like:

`[May-2017, April-2017, March-2017]`. Any idea guys?

Comment: make use of moment.js to figure out current month from the date and then figure out the next and previous month  from the month array which you should have in your component that has all the months

Answer (score 0):

Use getUTCMonth to get month index and make a array month with name to get the month name from index

```
   var month= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var date =new Date();
var n = date.getUTCMonth();

console.log(month[n] + ' ' +date.getUTCFullYear());
if(n != 0){
console.log(month[n-1] + ' ' +date.getUTCFullYear());
console.log(month[n-2] + ' ' +date.getUTCFullYear());
}else{
console.log(month[11] + ' ' +date.getUTCFullYear());
console.log(month[10] + ' ' +date.getUTCFullYear());
}
```

Comment: Do you realize it will fail if you are on january ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to maintain an array of every Months as string. and think to rotate year when needed :

```js
private months=["January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

private getPreviousMonth(d:Date,count:number){
    let yearDiff = Math.floor(count/12);
    let monthDiff= d.getUTCMonth() - (count % 12);
    let m = monthDiff>=0?monthDiff:12+monthDiff;
    let y= monthDiff>=0 ? d.getUTCFullYear()-yearDiff:d.getUTCFullYear()-(yearDiff+1);
    return `${this.months[m]}-${y}`;
}


private createMonthList(){
    let d = new Date();
    let months = [this.getPreviousMonth(d,0),thsi.getPreviousMonth(d,1),this.getPreviousMonth(d,2)];
    console.log(months);
}
```

But note that using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) can be a better idea if you need more date manipulations as they can be tedious.